# get values from array based on certain array element value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of struct, the struct contains 5 elements, I want to get all values in the array where  one element is equal to a certain value

Then I have an array of the above struct like so,

I want to print all elements in parr where parr.station equal to certain value

```
struct allproducts {
    let sendtime : String
    let max_value : String
    let station : String
    let product : String
    let availability : String
}

var parr = [allproducts]()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `parr` is already contains objects, you could simply achieve it by using [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994718-filter) method:

```
let filtered = parr.filter { $0.station == "your value" }
```

Obviously, you would change "your value" to your desired value.

***Sidebar note:*** Naming the struct should follow the *upper camel case* convention. You should call it: `AllProducts` or more logically `Product`.

Comment: am new to swift ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
let arryoucertainValue = parr.filter {$0.max_value <= 10}
```

use the filter function to get values from the array based on some conditions  for eg here I have fetched all element of the array which contains max_value property <= 10

Answer (score 0):

```
// declaring the model in the appropiate file
struct Product {
    let sendtime : String
    let max_value : String
    let station : String
    let product : String
    let availability : String
}


//instantiating the products
let prod1 = Product(station : "a", ....)
let prod2 = Product(station : "b", ...)
let prod3 = Product(station : "c", ...)




//adding the products to a collection
let allProducts= [prod1 , prod2 , prod3 ]

//filter all products based on a condition
let filteredArray = allProducts.filter { $0.station == "a") }

print(filteredArray)
```

I would recommend you to read a good book about introduction to OOP.

Comment: "I would recommend you to read a good book about introduction to OOP" if I'm not mistaking, such a task has nothing to do with knowing OOP :)

Comment: It has a bit Ahmad. Is not in the actual question about the filter function but in the naming of the struct. You cannot name a model AllProducts... you should be able to see that. PS: It is if I am not mistaken not "If I'm not mistaking"

Comment: Well, if you are meant by mentioning this the naming convention, I would say good point. But not the filtering...

Comment: That's what I meant indeed. You're right, the filtering function has nothing to do with OOP.